# how to access device battery level from lock screen

Tags: swift, notifications, battery, uidevice

I have been trying to replicate this feature found in the following app: [Charge Alarm](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/charge-alarm/id1049627090?mt=8)

My question is how are they able to access device's battery level when the  screen is locked and the app is in the background state?

They send notification when the app is in background state. And they send this notification when device reaches a certain battery level.

**NOTE:** They are not able to do this if the app is put in background state by pressing home button. But if user locks the screen while the app is active this feature works really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through this [this tutorial](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/)

and this seems to be working perfectly. I made only one change, that is, in info.plist file I added a new property `Application does not run in background` & gave it a value `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not Sure You can get that information on lock screen:

**Allow me to Tell you the whole process How to achieve the exact same functionality 
which is there in Charge Alarm App *It is really Simple* : Follow This :**

**Step 1 :**
You Need to set the `Background Fetch` ON in Capabilities of your project,

**Step 2 :**

**Turn On Battery Monitoring :** `UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true`
in your AppDelegate.

**Step 3 :**

Get the Battery Level :

```
var batteryLevel : Float {
    get {
          return UIDevice.current.batteryLevel 
        } 
    }
}
```

**Step 4 :**
Add the Observer in `viewDidLoad()` of your BaseViewController or any otherViewController :

```
    override func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(batteryLevelDidChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChange, object: nil)
      }
     func batteryLevelDidChange(_ notify:Notification){
          // write code to post a local notification on lock screen with text like :  " YOUR DEVICE IS NOW AT xx% "
      }
```

Now to Set Up Back Ground Modes : [Refer this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/890-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

**Step 5 :**

For Local Notification Setup : [Refer This](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-unusernotificationcenter-and-unnotificationrequest)

That's It, You have created the Same functionality, If you have any problem comment and I'll reply to earliest.

Comment: I have already tried your solution but that doesn't seem to be working for me... although I went through this link: https://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/ and it's working.